# Замена button type="button" на картинку

Tags: html, css

Проще говоря - есть стандартная кнопка - button type="button" которую нужно заменить на картинку. Сначала думал, что не сложно, теперь...) Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ решения проблемы.

Comment: А в чем проблемы (если можно, то с примером)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь - все решилось. Просто изначально неправильно начинал делать, теперь же все ясно.

Comment: А как привязать ссылку без CSS&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [`<button>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp), в нем можно использовать `<img .../>`, например:

```
<button type="button"><img .../></button>
```

Так-же есть [`<input type="image" src="..." />`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-image-tag.htm)

Comment: Можно и так, но через стили будет универсальнее, т.к. оформление отделено от разметки. А во-вторых, можно добавить дополнительные фичи, например изменение картинки при наведении или нажатии.

Answer (score 1):

А так не работает?

```
input[type="button"] {background: url(здесь УРЛ изображения) top left no-repeat;}
```

Вот [примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/zfhrP/) нарисовал!

Comment: Вот еще примерчик, для наглядности преимущества реализации через таблицу стилей:
http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/zfhrP/2/